ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
glitchにてpythonを用いてスクレイピングをしようとしています。
ターミナルにて
pip install bs4

を実行しましたが、
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

の際に
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

が発生します。
当方スクレイピングのためにpythonを始めたばかりで、あいにくほとんど知識がない状態です。
pythonのバージョンは3.7.10とのことですので、どなたか対処法をご教示ください。

スクレイピングは、サイトの管理者に許可を得ているとか、規約に従って専用の API にアクセスしているとかでなければ、迷惑行為になるかもしれないということは認識してますか？　クローラーを作って某図書館サイトにアクセスしたら業務妨害とかで逮捕された事例もありますので、甘く見ない方がいいと思います。逮捕までいかなくても、被害が深刻な場合は損害賠償の訴訟を受けるかもしれません。訴訟までいかなくても、アクセス遮断なら Web サーバーの設定で管理者だけの判断で容易に可能なので、多分に可能性はあると思います。帯域ごと遮断され、多数の利用者が巻き添えを喰らうことになるかもしれません。回答するのは迷惑行為の手助けをすることになるかもしれないということで、上記の辺りに問題がないことを示してもらえないと回答は得にくいと思います。

この記事 glitchでPythonを使いたい だと 3.x系の python や pip を使うためには 3 を付けて python3 とか pip3 という風に指定する必要があるようですが、そのようにしていますか？ あと単純にインストールする際のパッケージ名は bs4 ではなく beautifulsoup4 のようですね。beautifulsoup4 - PyPI bs4 だとこちら。bs4 - PyPI This is a dummy package designed to prevent namesquatting on PyPI. You should install beautifulsoup4 instead.

自己解決しました。
内容はコピーし忘れましたが、なんらかの形での警告があったため「$ /usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip」を実行した後に「pip install bs4」を試した所無事成功しました。
